# prometheus number of pod restarts not an integer

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to understand why prometheus is displaying the number of restarts as a decimal. If I have a query like: `delta(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[2d]) >= 1` which shows number of restarts over a long duration the result is:

```
value
11.135802469135804
2.0408163265306123
2.2
```

3 pods restarted 1 or more times in the last 2 days. However they restarted a non-integer amount of times? Increasing the duration out further to 4 days doesnt change the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Prometheus [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) of the `delta()` function:

> The delta is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in
> the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer
> result even if the sample values are all integers.

So, it seems to be about the match between your range selector (`2d`) and the metric timestamps. If they don't line up, you get fractional values.

Comment: Wouldnt i expect to see a change then when switching between 2 and 3 days?

Comment: Yes, it should vary. And it should vary with time as new values are added to the time series too.